# How to fix Typescript CannotDetermineTypeError

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs

Here is my code
Nestjs mongoose test.schema.ts

```
@Schema({ timestamps: true })
export class Tests {
  @Prop({ required: true, index: true })
  testid: number;

  @Prop({ required: false })
  extra_id: string | number;

  @Prop({ required: false })
  points: number;
}
```

for this, I'm getting below error,
CannotDetermineTypeError: Cannot determine a type for the "Tests.extra_id" field (union/intersection/ambiguous type was used). Make sure your property is decorated with a "`@Prop({ type: TYPE_HERE })`" decorator.
How to solve this.

Comment: Must a resolver be used in such a case? https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/unions-and-enums

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot declare Dynamic Type Like

```
 @Prop({ required: false })
 extra_id: string | number;
```

Mongoose support just One Type Like

```
@Prop({ type : String, required: false })
     extra_id: string;
```